# Microsoft Edge not show real sizes with brotli compresion

Tags: microsoft-edge, brotli

I'm testing some cloudfront content that is compressed with gzip and br.

I have tested the size of the objects with and without compression with curl and looks fine.

At Microsoft Edge the headers also looks fine

[image]

But the size of "transferred over the network" looks wrong, must be smaller.

[image]

On gzip compressed content y see the compressed size ("transferred over the network") and the real size ("resource size")

Is the brotli compression working fine or is just a UI issue?

Comment: Are you able to see the same behavior if you use other compression tools? What about other files?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, is not related with the compression algorisms, is caused by AWS Cloudfront.
It's compressing the data but not send back "Content-Length" and "Content-Encoding" headers.
I assume that the compression is working fine as I see with curl and is just a UI problem caused by AWS Cloudfront.